# How to add markers to maps in Xamarin

Tags: java, android, google-maps, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin Development and for some reason or another I have tried of implementing markers but I am unable to do it. I saw many websites but they seem out of date and some are very hard to understand.
I just want to add a simple marker to my maps sdk in Xamarin and I am highly confused.
Can someone please tell me how to put markers in map(Xamarin)Visual Studio Code.
I so far have just implemented a maps SDK to it.
Please help me.

the permission:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_API KEY" />  
  
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />  
  
</application>  
  
<user-permission android:name="com.googlemap.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />  
  
<uses-permission android:name="com.googlemap.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />  
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES" />  
  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  
  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

So far i have tried this:

```
LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(13.0291), Convert.ToDouble(80.2083));  
CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng, 15);  
GMap.MoveCamera(camera);  
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(latlng).SetTitle("Chennai");  
GMap.AddMarker(options);
```

But it doesn't work somehow.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you doing this in the OnMapReady callback?  Is the map itself displaying?

Comment: Yes the map itself is displaying.

Comment: I asked TWO questions :-). Have you followed the docs (and looked at the sample app) here -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api

Comment: Yes, the map displays, and yes I have seen it but it somehow gives me tonnes of errors.

Comment: You could download the source file about the map pins from the link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithmaps/

Comment: Thanks alot! I did fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Wendy Zang
Add Google Maps SDK,

Add this to xaml:

```
xmlns:mymap="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
```

Go to android manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
               android:value="AIzaSyAT0nnp4bD8nH3Yf-GPJYvjpfo-z4jFvVQ"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <uses-library android:name="org.apachie.http.legacy"
                   android:required="false"/>
```

Go to C#

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Position position = new Position(36.9628066, -122.0194722);
            MapSpan mapSpan = new MapSpan(position, 0.01, 0.01);
            Map map = new Map(mapSpan)
            {
               MapType = MapType.Hybrid
            
            };
            Content = map;
            Pin pin = new Pin
            {
                Label = "Santa HEY MAN",
                Address = "The city with a boardwalk",
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(36.9628066, -122.0194722)
            };
            map.Pins.Add(pin);

            Pin pin2 = new Pin
            {
                Label = "USA",
                Address = "2020",
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(36.9628066, -122.0194722)
            };
            map.Pins.Add(pin);


        }
```

That's how you do it!